# How can I set the Working Directory in Sublime Text 3?

Tags: html, sublimetext3

I am using Sublime Text 3 for a web design project. How can you set the working directory to a specific folder in sublime text?

It seems that default working directory in Sublime for a html file is wherever it has been saved. I would like to change the working directory for my html files to a folder that contains all of the files for my project. Hence, the following line of code works if my html files are in a html folder:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/stylesheet1">
</head>
```

Thanks!

Comment: Are you using a `.sublime-project` to set up the parameters for your project? If not, that's the solution.

Comment: Add one or more directories to your project using: `Menu --> Project --> Add Folder to Project`. I suggest you do a web search for something like: `projects tutorial Sublime Text 3`.